# What Horoscope or Astrology software is available?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for Horoscope or Astrology software in ubuntu especially for 9.04 or 10.04 version.

Comment: Is your question about astrology software or is it about upgrading? Please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: Not to be that guy, but I want to make sure you're aware that Astrology has absolutely no scientific backing. It's not my business what you do on your own time, but I hope that you are under no delusions that it's a real science.

Comment: @user6106 I have removed the second question regarding how to upgrade your system. Please [Ask](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) that in another question.

Answer (score 20):

I just wrote this... Seems like it would be as good as anything else.

```
if [ $[`expr '(' $RANDOM '*' 2 / 32767 ')'`] -eq 1 ]; then echo "Today will be awesome"; else echo "Back to bed, today will suck"; fi
```

A shorter version, for Bash:

```
(($RANDOM % 2)) && echo "Today will be a good day" || echo "Back to bed, today will stink"
```

Comment: +1 @oli That's a fantastic implementation.  I've actually been able to make it more useful for me -- I hope you don't mind my fork -- by piping all the output to /dev/null.

Comment: This should work with any version of Ubuntu. I just tested it on 12.04 and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 8):

Add wanda the fish to your gnome-panel, it gives fortunes. If you follow what it tells you, then it works for sure.

Here is a screenshot of the applet in the panel applets list:
[image]

And one of the fish telling you your unfortunate future D: (oh no!)
[image]

*please remember, wanda is a fish... be careful trusting her too much.*

Answer (score 5):

Check this http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Environment/Screenlets/Horoscope-36983.shtml

This is a screenlet  that displays today's forecast from astrology.yahoo.com.
You can configure it to show your zodiac in the screenlet.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

[Zodiac](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zodiac-app/) seemingly works out-of-the box. Screenshot: [image: Screenshot of zodiac chart].

Answer (score 2):

openastro.org is a good one.

Here is a tutorial to upgrade from 9.04 to 10.04:

http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/05/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-9-04-jaunty-to-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx-directly/

Comment: The question that was merged here, he was asking how to upgrade from 9.04 to 10.10.

Answer (score 1):

Any horoscope/astrology app is only as good as its input. So you won't find much, there could be something that reads it data back from sites like http://astrology.yahoo.com.

As for your upgrade question, you should upgrade to 9.10 and then to 10.04. The `Update Manager` (System > Administration > Upgrade Manager) will ask you to upgrade. If it doesn't you might need to update the `Software Sources` (System > Administration > Software Sources) to warn you about new release. In the `Updates` tab change the `new distribution releases`.