# What Horoscope software is available?

Tags: software-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Horoscope or Astrology software is available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13351/what-horoscope-or-astrology-software-is-available)

I am looking for horoscope software in ubuntu